# Cannot save page settings in TYPO3 7.3 (yellow warning sign)

Tags: typo3

Since yesterday, a very weird behaviour happens to be introduced to my TYPO3 instance. The yellow warning sign is displayed beneath the "Resources" tab in page settings preventing me from saving any changes. But it's not displaying beneath any field that could be the problem. I can't seem to remember having changed anything in the template's TS setup. Please tell me if you need any more information.

[image: Screenshot of problematic view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the extension [Compatibility Mode for TYPO3 CMS 6.x](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/compatibility6) (extension key: compatibility6; version: 7.6.0 stable) caused this behaviour.
Everything worked fine again after uninstalling it.

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot shows twice the field "General Record Storage Page". There should only be one.

Futhermore I'd recommend to upgrade to version 7.6 as it is the only release branch for version 7 that is getting security and bugfix updates.

HTH